# Organizing code: redirect without changing url using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a site with a main page (business stuff) and a some folder with separate projects living in different folders:

- index.html
- /js
- /css
- /images
- /blog
- /project

I want to move all main page assets to a folder called "site". What I want is an structure like the following:

- /site

  - index.html
  - /js
  - /css
  - /images
- /blog
- /project

When my users go to www.example.com, browser should load /site resources without changing url, and when they go to www.example.com/blog browser should load /blog resources (as expected).

I'm trying to use .htaccess document on my root folder, and put this on it:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule /(.*) /site [R]
```

But it doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[R]` flag causes a HTTP redirect to be issued to the browser.

Instead, try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
# Ensure you do not running in redirection loop
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/site/
# Proceed if target is not a directory (handle accessing /blog, etc)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Proceed if target is not a file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# Redirect all incoming requests to site/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /site/$1 [L]
# Redirect domain itself to the main site file (index.html, index.php, etc)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ index.html [L]
```

Note that you should:

- Replace all instances of `site` with your sub directory
- Replace `example.com` with your TLD domain.

Comment: Thanks. I tried your solution but when I enter on www.example.com nothing is loaded (only file tree). Should I need to define a rule for every asset in order to be loaded correctly? For example, index.html when I enter on /.

Comment: I updated the answer. I added comments for better understanding. Good luck!

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks vitozev!